# Android studio Instrumented Test stuck at: Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing, instrumented-test

I have encountered a problem that when I tried to run Android Instrument test, android studio will start building, everything is good until it stuck to this line

"> Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest"

and run for the next 2hrs and never proceed the actual test. What I have seen is that the test app has been successfully built into my device but just won't open and run.

Strange thing is that I have built successfully once before, but after when I tried to build again, it never success anymore. Even when I didn't change my code.

Here are the things I had tried

- Update Android Studio - version 2021.3.1 Patch 1
- Clean and Rebuild Project
- Invalidate cache and Restart
- Update SDK build tools
- Restart Computer
- Restart phone device

But still can't build!

Here is my instrument test class screen shot

[image: Here is my instrument test class]

running process screen shot

[image]

[image]

Has anyone had this problem before?

Comment: I'm stuck at the same spot today although yesterday the same tests were running fine... did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Got the same problem :(

Comment: Same problem. The team at Google clearly does not care about major issues like this. It is such a time waster trying to debug a test that keeps crashing in debug mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I started seeing the same issue after upgrading to `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5` and
`androidx.test:core-ktx:1.5.0`

You can try to downgrade the versions to previous ones, or you can use next dependencies instead:

`debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing-manifest:1.6.0-alpha04") androidTestImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.0-alpha04")`

You can find more info in this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128612536

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my problem, downgrading the version works, thanks!

Comment: Downgrading to `1.5.4.` still yields the same issue

Comment: Did not fix my issue

Comment: Which downgraded version it works for?

Answer (score 17):

Found answer to this issue. Apparently when you open logcat side by side when building, you encounter this error which is the root cause of build never completing:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.PlatformTestStorageRegistry"
```

Add this dependency to get this class:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.test:monitor:1.6.1"
```

You're good to go :)

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following dependency:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"
```

Comment: This worked for me when I upgraded to `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.2`, thanks!