# Running Tests doesn't work properly. Test Results 0/0 Android Instrumented Tests

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, testing, instrumented-test

After updating my project with following  dependencies my tests stoped running.

```
    mockitoVersion = '5.3.0'
    dexMakerVersion = '2.28.3'
    espressoVersion = '3.5.1'
```

--

```
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion"

    androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$dexMakerVersion"

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$espressoVersion"
```

I can click on button Run and it seems like running. But nothing happenned. Gradle build running endless and test results 0/0.

[image]

I have tried:

1. update my studio (now it is Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1)
2. update Gradle (8.0.0)
3. invalidate cash and restart (several times)
4. clean and rebuild
5. update libraries
6. I have testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner" already.

I don't understand where is a problem. Please help me to run my tests.

P.S it seems like unit tests work fine. So the problem is with Instrumented  Tests

[image]

Comment: Open the "Build" tab at the bottom. You will probably find an error there

Comment: @IvanWooll there are no errors. As I already told gradle build running seems endless.
file:///Users/ksenia/Desktop/Screenshot%202023-05-01%20at%2012.21.05.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a working solution here:
[Android studio Instrumented Test stuck at: Task :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74608921/android-studio-instrumented-test-stuck-at-task-appconnecteddebugandroidtest)

So I changed mine:

```
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.5.5"
```

to

```
    debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing-manifest:1.6.0-alpha04")
    debugImplementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.6.0-alpha04")
```